# AnalogOnScreenControl listener in andengine

Tags: android, andengine

I am using Andengine for developing my game.I have used AnalogOnScreenControl in my game.By the help of some tutorials I am able to move my sprite using this control.And I used following code for that purpose.

```
    final AnalogOnScreenControl analogOnScreenControl = new AnalogOnScreenControl(100, 100, this.camera, this.mOnScreenControlBaseTextureRegion, this.mOnScreenControlKnobTextureRegion, 0.1f, 200, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager(), new IAnalogOnScreenControlListener() {
    @Override
    public void onControlChange(final BaseOnScreenControl pBaseOnScreenControl, final float pValueX, final float pValueY) {
        physicsHandler.setVelocity(pValueX * 100, pValueY * 100);

      }

    @Override
    public void onControlClick(final AnalogOnScreenControl pAnalogOnScreenControl) {
        player.registerEntityModifier(new SequenceEntityModifier(new ScaleModifier(0.25f, 1, 1.5f), new ScaleModifier(0.25f, 1.5f, 1)));
    }
});
```

I am using a tiled image and animating the sprite using,

```
player.animate(new long[]{200, 200, 200}, 3, 5, true);
```

.I want to specify the order of animating sprites according to the user input from AnalogOnScreenControl.Means, when user make a user input in AnalogOnScreenControl I need to listen it and set the sequence of animation according to that. Can I detect in which side the analog stick is moved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution from AndEngine forum.Here is the code,

```
public class TestActivity extends BaseGameActivity {

    private TMXTiledMap mTMXTiledMap;
    private BoundCamera mBoundChaseCamera;

    private static final int CAMERA_WIDTH = 480;
private static final int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 320;

    private Texture mTexture;
    private Texture mTexturePlayer;
    private TiledTextureRegion mPlayerTextureRegion;
    private Texture mOnScreenControlTexture;
    private TextureRegion mOnScreenControlBaseTextureRegion;
    private TextureRegion mOnScreenControlKnobTextureRegion;

    private DigitalOnScreenControl mDigitalOnScreenControl;

    private enum PlayerDirection{
            NONE,
            UP,
            DOWN,
            LEFT,
            RIGHT
    }
    private PlayerDirection playerDirection = PlayerDirection.DOWN;


    @Override
    public Engine onLoadEngine() {
            this.mBoundChaseCamera = new BoundCamera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
            return new Engine(new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE, new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), this.mBoundChaseCamera));
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadResources() {
            TextureRegionFactory.setAssetBasePath("gfx/");

            this.mTexture = new Texture(32, 32, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);
            this.mTexturePlayer = new Texture(128, 128, TextureOptions.DEFAULT);

            this.mOnScreenControlTexture = new Texture(256, 128, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);
            this.mOnScreenControlBaseTextureRegion = TextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(this.mOnScreenControlTexture, this, "onscreen_control_base.png", 0, 0);
            this.mOnScreenControlKnobTextureRegion = TextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(this.mOnScreenControlTexture, this, "onscreen_control_knob.png", 128, 0);

            this.mPlayerTextureRegion = TextureRegionFactory.createTiledFromAsset(this.mTexturePlayer, this, "hero.png", 0, 0, 3, 4);

            this.mEngine.getTextureManager().loadTextures(this.mTexture, this.mOnScreenControlTexture);
            this.mEngine.getTextureManager().loadTexture(this.mTexturePlayer);
    }

    @Override
    public Scene onLoadScene() {
            this.mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new FPSLogger());

            final Scene scene = new Scene();

            try {
                    final TMXLoader tmxLoader = new TMXLoader(this, this.mEngine.getTextureManager(), TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA, null);
                    this.mTMXTiledMap = tmxLoader.loadFromAsset(this, "tmx/test.tmx");

            } catch (final TMXLoadException tmxle) {
                    Debug.e(tmxle);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < this.mTMXTiledMap.getTMXLayers().size(); i++){
                    TMXLayer layer = this.mTMXTiledMap.getTMXLayers().get(i);
                    scene.attachChild(layer);
            }

            /* Make the camera not exceed the bounds of the TMXEntity. */
            final TMXLayer tmxLayer = this.mTMXTiledMap.getTMXLayers().get(0);
            this.mBoundChaseCamera.setBounds(0, tmxLayer.getWidth(), 0, tmxLayer.getHeight());
            this.mBoundChaseCamera.setBoundsEnabled(true);


            /* Calculate the coordinates for the player, so it's centered on the camera. */
            final int centerX = (CAMERA_WIDTH - this.mPlayerTextureRegion.getTileWidth()) / 2;
            final int centerY = (CAMERA_HEIGHT - this.mPlayerTextureRegion.getTileHeight()) / 2;

            /* Create the sprite and add it to the scene. */
            final AnimatedSprite player = new AnimatedSprite(centerX, centerY, this.mPlayerTextureRegion);
            this.mBoundChaseCamera.setChaseEntity(player);
            final PhysicsHandler physicsHandler = new PhysicsHandler(player);
            player.registerUpdateHandler(physicsHandler);
            scene.attachChild(player);

            this.mDigitalOnScreenControl = new DigitalOnScreenControl(0, CAMERA_HEIGHT - this.mOnScreenControlBaseTextureRegion.getHeight(), this.mBoundChaseCamera, this.mOnScreenControlBaseTextureRegion, this.mOnScreenControlKnobTextureRegion, 0.1f, new IOnScreenControlListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onControlChange(final BaseOnScreenControl pBaseOnScreenControl, final float pValueX, final float pValueY) {
                            if (pValueY == 1){
                                    // Up
                                    if (playerDirection != PlayerDirection.UP){
                                            player.animate(new long[]{200, 200, 200}, 0, 2, true);
                                            playerDirection = PlayerDirection.UP;
                                    }
                            }else if (pValueY == -1){
                                    // Down
                                    if (playerDirection != PlayerDirection.DOWN){
                                            player.animate(new long[]{200, 200, 200}, 9, 11, true);
                                            playerDirection = PlayerDirection.DOWN;
                                    }
                            }else if (pValueX == -1){
                                    // Left
                                    if (playerDirection != PlayerDirection.LEFT){
                                            player.animate(new long[]{200, 200, 200}, 3, 5, true);
                                            playerDirection = PlayerDirection.LEFT;
                                    }
                            }else if (pValueX == 1){
                                    // Right
                                    if (playerDirection != PlayerDirection.RIGHT){
                                            player.animate(new long[]{200, 200, 200}, 6, 8, true);
                                            playerDirection = PlayerDirection.RIGHT;
                                    }
                            }else{
                                    if (player.isAnimationRunning()){
                                            player.stopAnimation();
                                            playerDirection = PlayerDirection.NONE;
                                    }
                            }
                            physicsHandler.setVelocity(pValueX * 60, pValueY * 60);
                    }
            });
            this.mDigitalOnScreenControl.getControlBase().setBlendFunction(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
            this.mDigitalOnScreenControl.getControlBase().setAlpha(0.5f);
            this.mDigitalOnScreenControl.getControlBase().setScaleCenter(0, 128);
            this.mDigitalOnScreenControl.getControlBase().setScale(1.25f);
            this.mDigitalOnScreenControl.getControlKnob().setScale(1.25f);
            this.mDigitalOnScreenControl.refreshControlKnobPosition();

            scene.setChildScene(this.mDigitalOnScreenControl);

            return scene;

    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadComplete() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

}

Comment: this solution for DigitalOnScreenControl. For AnalogOnScreenControl you can find angle `MathUtils.radToDeg((float)Math.atan2(pValueX, pValueY))`